# in Python how do I print the result of a calculation and then save the result to a variable?

Tags: python, variables, printing, command

I am learning python and I am challenging myself to write a little program that asks the user the base price of a car, then saves the base price to a variable called `base`. It has two other variables called `tax` and `license` that are percentages. So it gets the base price, gets `seven (7)` percent of the `base` price, and adds it to the base price. It does the same for the license fee, etc.

However, what I want to know is that when it runs:
`print "\nAfter taxes the price is: ", (base * tax / 100 + base)`
how can I save the result to another variable so that the next line I dont have to write:
`print "\nAfter taxes and license fee the price is: ", (base*tax / 100)+(base*license /100) + base?` Rewriting it feels very redundant and like I'm wasting time by calculation something that has already been calculated.

I want to save the result of the first `print` line to a variable called `after_tax` so that then I could write:
`print "\nAfter taxes and license fee the price is: ", after_tax + (base*license /100)`

(I want the first `print` command to also save the result of the math calculation to a variable called `after_tax` so that I can reuse the result without having to retype out the entire calculation to get the result again).

#### Below is the code in it's entirety:

```
#Car salesman calculations program.

base = int(raw_input("What is the base price of the car?" + "\n"))
tax = 7

license = 4

dealer_prep = 500

destination_charge = 1000


print "\nAfter taxes the price is: ", (base * tax / 100 + base)

print "\nAfter taxes and license fee the price is: ", (base*tax / 100)+(base*license /100) + base

print "\nAfter taxes and license fee and dealer prep the price is: ", (base*tax / 100)+(base*license /100) + base + dealer_prep

print "\nAfter taxes, license fees, dealer prep, and destination charge, the total price is: ", (base*tax / 100)+(base*license /100) + base + dealer_prep + destination_charge

raw_input("\nPress the enter key to close the window.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do all your calculations up front. i recommend giving the variables (a, b, c, etc) smarter names than I did here, but this is illustrative enough.

```
a = (base * tax / 100)
b = (base*license /100)
c = a + b + base
d = c + dealer_prep
e = d + destination_charge

print "\nAfter taxes the price is: ", a + base
print "\nAfter taxes and license fee the price is: ", c
print "\nAfter taxes and license fee and dealer prep the price is: ", d
print "\nAfter taxes, license fees, dealer prep, and destination charge, the total price is: ", e

raw_input("\nPress the enter key to close the window.")
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. This works, of course. I will use this.

Comment: haha, sometimes it's the obvious answers that are hardest to see ;-)

Comment: you can select the best answer as the correct one. both the user that answers and the asker receive reputation points for it.

Answer (score 4):

In Python you can't do this in the same line. But what you can do is define the `after_tax` variable first, and then just print it out:

```
after_tax = base * tax / 100 + base
print "\nAfter taxes the price is: ", after_tax
```

Comment: Thank you! Someone beat you to it, but at least two identical answers usually confirms it's correct. I appreciate it.